# google DFA reporting api get report as zip

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to download a report using  the google DFA reporting api .net client in a zip format but i am always getting back a csv. I am using the MediaDownloader class to download the report for the url provided for the report. I have enabled the GzipEnabled property on the service but it does not affect the response
Any help is much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **GzipEnabled** property only affects data while it is in transit. When **GzipEnabled** is True, the data packets are compressed during transmission. Upon arrival, the data are decompressed.

**GzipEnabled** is not intended to cause a compressed file to be created.

Comment: is there a property that i can set to get a compressed report instead of csv or excel?

Comment: Regarding the GZipEnabled - Feel free to read more in the library documentation - https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/performance#gzip

Comment: Thank you for the comments. so i am going to assume that there is no way to get a compressed file from DFA as of now . If i am completely wrong pls let me know.